# JAutodoc: getter comment template is merged with default comment behavior

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jautodoc

I am trying to configure JAutodoc such that getter comments are generated containing only the `@returns` tag, like so:

```
/**
 * @returns The non-null {@linkplain Foo foo} of this {@link IBar}.
 */
public Foo getFoo();
```

I have configured my getter template to produce this:

[image]

However, something must be wrong with my general JAutodoc settings, because what I get instead is a hybrid of my template and a comment parsed from the method name:

```
/**
 * Get foo.
 * @returns The non-null {@linkplain Foo foo} of this {@link IBar}.
 */
public Foo getFoo();
```

These are my settings:

[image]

I have removed the 'get' replacement from the replacements list, as well as unchecked the 'etter from field comment' setting as advised in [this discussion](http://sourceforge.net/p/jautodoc/discussion/601548/thread/d87981ef/), but it has not made a noticeable difference. I have also attempted to uncheck the 'Create comment from element name' setting, despite my example getter being part of an interface (in which case there *is* no element to get the comment from), but JAutodoc doesn't seem to care about that.

I have also tried restarting Eclipse after making each of these changes, in case that mattered. So far, nothing is working. It almost appears as if the comment behavior of getters is hard-coded. Can someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

JAutodoc, in its current form, can not do what you want it to do. This is because you are asking for incomplete Javadocs.

### Details

(This was fun, and I hope you appreciate the effort :-)

This is a case where you are asking JAutodoc to create incomplete Javadocs. i.e. you are asking for no documentation in the Javadoc. (I personally find the repetitiveness on simple getter annoying too BTW).

The steps that JAutodoc are going through internally is:

1. Applying your template, so the comment looks exactly as you want - for a moment in time.

This is the bit of code that applies the template. Using your example, the `member` parameter below is your `getFoo` method and, as there is no existing comment in your code when you first apply the auto-comment, so the `jdi` parameter is empty (`jdi.isEmpty() == true`).

When the template is applied, `text` looks exactly as you want it too. `text` gets parsed just as any Javadoc comment would and returned.

From `net.sf.jautodoc.source.JavadocCreator`:

```
public JavadocInfo applyTemplate(final IMember member, final JavadocInfo jdi) throws Exception {
    final JavadocInfo templateJdi = new JavadocInfo();
    final String text = JAutodocPlugin.getContext().getTemplateManager().applyTemplate(member,
            config.getProperties());
    if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
        templateJdi.parseJavadoc(text);
    }
    return jdi.isEmpty() ? templateJdi : jdi.merge(templateJdi);
}
```

2. Now the `JavadocInfo` that was returned from `applyTemplate` is passed to `createJavadoc`. In `createJavadoc` the code checks if there is a comment (excluding the `@param`s, `@return`, etc). As there is not any, it tries to insert some automatically from the information available. Simplistically, it just un-camel-cases the name of the method and makes that the comment.

From `net.sf.jautodoc.source.JavadocCreator`

```
public String createJavadoc(final IMethod method, final String indent, final String lineSeparator,
        final JavadocInfo jdi) throws JavaModelException {

    final List<String> text = jdi.getComment();
    if (text.isEmpty()) {
        if (config.isCreateDummyComment()) {
            if (method.isConstructor()) {
                text.add(Constants.JDOC_CONSTRUCTOR);
            }
            else if (method.isMainMethod()) {
                text.add(Constants.JDOC_MAIN);
            }
            else {
                String comment = CommentManager.createComment(config, method.getElementName(),
                        CommentManager.METHOD, true, true, CommentManager.FIRST_TO_UPPER);
                text.add(comment + Constants.DOT);
            }
        }
        else {
            text.add("");
        }
    }
    else {
        checkForDot(text);
    }
```

Now the code that calls the above two methods is this:

From `net.sf.jautodoc.source.SourceManipulator.addJavadoc(IMember)`:

```
if (config.isCreateDummyComment()) {
    jdi = javadocCreator.applyTemplate(member, jdi);
}
newJavadoc = javadocCreator.createJavadoc((IMethod) member, indent, lineDelimiter, jdi);
```

As you can see from these code snippets, both applying your template and creating the comment part (that you don't want!) is controlled by the same if statement `config.isCreateDummyComment()`. That if statement connects to the `Create comment from element name` option.

### Examples

This issue is not happening because the method is a getter, but applies everywhere. Assume you have this bit of code:

```
/**
 * @param myFirstParam this is important and I documented it
 */
public int doThisAndThat(int myFirstParam, int anotherParamHere) {
    return 0;
}
```

And you apply JAutodoc to it (with `Complete existing Javadoc`) then you get:

With `Create comment from element name` unset:

```
/**
 * 
 *
 * @param myFirstParam this is important and I documented it
 * @param anotherParamHere 
 * @return 
 */
public int doThisAndThat(int myFirstParam, int anotherParamHere) {
    return 0;
}
```

With `Create comment from element name` set:

```
/**
 * Do this and that.
 *
 * @param myFirstParam this is important and I documented it
 * @param anotherParamHere the another param here
 * @return the int
 */
public int doThisAndThat(int myFirstParam, int anotherParamHere) {
    return 0;
}
```

### Getting the source

I couldn't find the source on any of the usual suspects (github, etc), but it is available for download here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jautodoc/files/jautodoc/1.13.0/

So you could, if you desired, edit the source and rebuild your plug-ins. Or file a feature request with the dev.

### In Conclusion

JAutodoc, in its current form, can not do what you ask it to do. However, this is essentially by design, because if you say you want to `Create comment from element name` automatically (internally called Create Dummy Comment) then you want fully complete Javadoc to be created for you.

Finally, keep in mind if there is no comment, then nothing appears in the method summary table and your generated Javadocs simply look incomplete.

Comment: Ah, well done! The effort you've made is very much appreciated.